# Copy columns data from one table to another

Tags: mysql

Please could someone help, i'm really stuck.

I have a mysql database with two tables ( with thousands of rows ), each table has a column called 'map' and i need to copy all the rows from one tables column to the 'map' column of the other table?

I know it seems simple but i'm getting in a jumble

Comment: Please edit your question to include one or more of your attempts at a solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work.

```
UPDATE table_to
       JOIN table_from
       <put join here>
SET table_to.map = table_from.map
```

Comment: Hi, thanks.I just tried that and the query ran but copied 'null' into all the rows instead of the value in the original table, it also only updated a third of the rows?

Comment: Can you post the SQL statement you tried?  Also if you could show your table structures and or go to www.sqlfiddle.com and put some sample data it would be much easier to solve.

Comment: There are two tables, newforummembers and members444, each has a comlumn named 'map' this is the sql :                                        
    newforummembers
    JOIN members444 ON newforummembers.map = members444.map
SET
    newforummembers.map = members444.map

Comment: You are joining on the map field, so you will only update records where the map fields are already equal.  In other words your query won't really change anything.  Is there another field that ties the two tables together, like member_id perhaps?  If so, that's what you should be joining on.

Answer (score 0):

Or just simply use the next. This will insert all rows from table_from with the value from the map column to table_to's map column.

```
INSERT INTO table_to
(map)
SELECT map FROM table_from
```

Comment: Hi, that updated all the rows but still copied 'null' into every row rather than the values in the original tables column

Comment: Hi, yes, this inserts all rows, independently whether their value is null or not. You can filter out any values before inserting if that is a requirement:
`INSERT INTO table_to
(map)
SELECT map FROM table_from WHERE map IS NOT NULL` also if you want to insert only unique values (eg no duplicates) then use `INSERT INTO table_to
(map)
SELECT DISTINCT map FROM table_from WHERE map IS NOT NULL`

Comment: I need it to copy all the rows in the column, at the moment it is just updating the members444 map column but filling it with nulls rather than the values which are in the original table.

Comment: If it filling it with nulls then might be a difference in how the map column is defined in the two tables. Make sure that they have the same definition. Also consider any other constraints on the table - like unique index.

Answer (score 0):

copy data from one table to another in mysql

INSERT INTO `database1`.`table1` SELECT * FROM `database2`.`table2` ;